# No. of comparisons in merging lists

Tags: sorting, merge, time-complexity

I am confused over the best case, the average case and the worst-case for the number of comparisons done by the merge function in merge sort.I have the following questions:

1.If I pass in a list of unsorted elements that give the worst-case time in merge sort, will it also be the case for maximum number of comparisons?

2.Suppose I pass in a list of size N that takes the maximum time to be sorted.The number of comparisons in this case would be N-1.Am I right?

3.What will be the best case for number of comparisons?

Someone please help me.I studied too much and now am confused.

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps to merge sort:

1. Split the list (approximately in half). (If there's only one element, you're done).
2. Sort each list
3. Merge each list.

Only the merge operation requires comparisons, and in every case you need to do O(n) comparisons.

The best case for comparisons is when the list is already ordered; in that case, you'll be comparing each element of the first list to the first element of the second list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] ++ [5, 6, 7, 8]:

1 > 5
2 > 5
3 > 5
4 > 5
```

After those 4 comparisons, the sorting is done.

The worst case is alternating elements:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7] ++ [2, 4, 6, 8]

1 > 2 -> Result = [1]
3 > 2 -> Result = [1, 2]
4 > 3 -> Result = [1, 2, 3]
5 > 4 -> Result = [1, 2, 3, 4]
6 > 5 -> Result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
7 > 6 -> Result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
8 > 7 -> Result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] (Once the first list is finished, no more comparisons are necessary.)
```

However, while each `merge` operation is O(n) (n/2 in the best case, n-1 in the worst case), the total number of comparisons will be O(log n).

Comment: Or bottom up (more common in actual libraries, such as C++ std::stable_sort), skip the recursion and split the list into n runs of size 1. For a pure merge sort, top down or bottom up, no sorting is done, the list is divided until run size == 1, and then pairs of runs are merged until run size >= list size. So all of the "sorting" is done by merging already sorted runs, where a run size of 1 can be considered already sorted. The number of compares is O(n log(n)).